# mySql table data can't be viewed using SELECT statement only give empty result

Tags: mysql

In my test project MySQL table is created to store data (State, District, Area) I declare these columns as text. when submit form data saved to database. but when try to review using SELECT statement with WHERE clause it give empty result `` SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE district='districtName'; ``. please advice what is the error.

Comment: The query is syntactically correct so amongst other possible reasons fir nothing being returned the table is empty or there are no rows where the where clause is satisfied. please add sample data as text. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=170c70071833515761443f25b118fab0

Comment: INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `password`, `code`, `status`, `compName`, `state`, `nic`, `photo`, `voice_no`, `whatsapp_no`, `farm_address`, `resi_address`, `province`, `district`) VALUES
(28, 'Extension without Buy', 'eprocu@naiua.col', '2586', 0, 'verified', '', 'Mr', '3014', '1405221652504291bald-eagles.jpg', 87, 87, '', 'Eo home only', 'Western', ' Colombo'),
(29, 'District Officer test', 'manoj1@gmail.com', '2569', 0, 'verified', '', 'Mr', '2001', '1405221652528390eagle2.jpg', 65, 65, '', 'Residense test3', 'Sabaragamuwa', ' Kegalle'),

Comment: Did you notice there's an extra space before ' Colombo' and ' Kegalle'? You'll have to add the space in your query too: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE district=' Colombo';`

Comment: Yes, its working. This space comes from database when convert id no to its name in district name table in my database. even i didn't guess it. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

can you share more details of database
like name of database and how many records in the database

Comment: This is a comment and it should be posted as a comment.  We know that you can't post a comment yet.  But you are not allowed to use a question as a comment.

Comment: database name is 'users' and I'm only testing these database therefore only add 30 records